# powershell script to monitor mcAfee status

Tags: powershell

I am very new to powershell. Is there any way through which we may monitor Mcafee update

scenario: if its not gettting updated and failing, we shall recive mail that update failed

i checked for the log file i.e C:\ProgramData\McAfee\DesktopProtection\Updatelog.txt

where all the logs are getting updated daily.

Anyway throgh which we may filter data from the text file and copy into another text file and filtering could be when it fails or the keyword"Update process failed". the same will be copied in another text file
and in a way i can monitor the other text file.

and the text file is getting updated with timestamp

Comment: Doesn't your McAfee server management console (assuming you're using a product that's managed in this way) have a way to monitor the status of each client?

Comment: yes Alroc exactly just a product, well that said i am thinking or over here my requirement is if its not updating or its failing, it should be notified to us.

Comment: Right. So my point is your management console should be monitoring this and be configurable to send alerts. Don't reinvent the wheel, someone has already made a better one than you will.

Comment: that said the management console is Ok to run but will send alerts with whole string e.g 4 warnings in C__ProgramData_McAfee_DesktopProtection_UpdateLog_txt.protocol-2014-06-13-17-32-00;  where i am configuring to monitor for just the keyword 06, which ain't helping me, so how do we proceed,, any suggestion?

Comment: Configuring your monitoring console to send the appropriate alerts is a completely different question, and you probably want to start with McAfee's support resources.

Answer (score 1):

I would look the DatVersion or DatDATE from the registry and send email if it not match your requirements

```
$mcafee=get-itemproperty HKLM:\software\wow6432Node\mcafee\avengine  
$mcafee | select EngineVersionMajor, EngineVersionMinor, AvDatVersion, AvDatDate
```

Comment: i presented that but as a specfic requirement they just want to monitor when it had no been updated or failing .